# Arduino Uno and enc28j60 with UIPEthernet library

Tags: webserver, arduino

I have Arduino uno r3 with enc28j60 ethernet shield connected with Livebox router and I am trying to use the UIPEthernet library ( https://github.com/ntruchsess/arduino_uip ).
I found this web page: http://www.lucadentella.it/en/2013/12/10/enc28j60-e-arduino-16/ and I made changes in the official WebServer sketch as it was said there.
The problem is that in the Serial Port Monitor I only see "server is at 192.168.1.177". It should be there much more informations like in the web page mentioned before. The address 192.168.177 in my browser is also unavaible.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure that 192.168.1.177 is an appropriate address for your network.  What is the ip address of the machine running the browser?

Post the network configuration of the machine with the browser here (I'm assuming 192.168.177 is a typo and you meant to type 192.168.1.177 and are typing this into your web browser).